# Solfa style music notation (Carnatic)

Tags: music, vertical-alignment, spacing

I'm looking for a way to typeset Carnatic (Indian) music. The notation system is textual, similar to solfa, with some symbols like comma, semi-colon and | for durations, and bar lines.

Fine control for notes, phrases, and spacing between is needed. 
Control over Vertical alignment is needed too.

[image: Carnatic Music Score with LaTeX]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{Ananth}
\begin{document}

$ \begin{array}{llll|ll|ll||}
\\
g,m,    & d,,,  & nndn  & \dot{s},,, &
d n s n     & , d d n   & d d m g   & m g r s \\
nin ne  & ko-   & - & ri- &
yun & ,nna  & ---ra & ---- \\
\\
rs\d{nd}    &, \d{n}sr  & snsg  &mddn   &
\dot{s}\dot{g}\dot{r}\dot{s}    & nd\dot{s}n    &dmgd   &mgrs \\
ne--na  &--rum- &chi--- &nan--- &
nee--lu &--ko-  &---ra  &----\\

\end{array} $

\paragraph* { another array  \break}

$
\begin{array}{llllllllllllllll|}
s&g&r&s&n&d&s&n&d&m&g&d&m&g&r&s\\
ne&&&lu&&&ko&&&&&ra&&&\\
\end{array} $

\paragraph*{That was array. Now using ams' align package}

 \begin{align}
rsn & d && ,nsr && snsg && mddn | \\
ne-- & na   &&--rum-    &&chi---    &&nan---    \\
\intertext{and}
sgrs    && ndsn && dmgd && mgrs || \\
nee--lu &&--ko- &&---ra &&----\\
\end{align} 

verdict: Tables, Arrays, ams' align package - all  are good for swara notation. Not upto the mark for synchronizing lyrics.


\end{document}
```

Grid like, fixed spacing between notes is possible - Tables etc., and are widely used too. I'm looking for flexible spacing between musical *phrases*, and points of alignment between lines. Inspired by Lilypond, one could say.

Is it possible to do these with LaTeX? If so, how?

I've tried using `array`s and `align` (ams) with not so satisfactory results.

Comment: Till a better answer comes along: the TeX FAQ has a list of packages for [typsetting music](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=music) in TeX. And there's also Lilypond. Have you tried some of these, and what do they fail at?

Comment: What ShreevatsaR said...  (Perhaps you should promote that to an answer rather than a comment?)

Comment: Lilypond produces excellent music score, but in western staff notation/guitar tab etc. I'm using lilypond for such scores. Indian music notation is not graphic, it's mostly textual. Most folks use a word processor/ spreadsheet to get it done. Problem is the score becomes a 'grid' and 'phrases' are difficult to distinguish. I will add an image and make my point more clear.

Comment: Is this correct? Each "phrase" is a block of text in two lines with notes above lyrics, and you want to typeset these "phrases"/blocks with flexible spacing and alignment.

Comment: absolutely correct ShreevastaR

Comment: I had never seen this notation before, but at a first glance it seems to have a lot in common with linguistic glosses. Perhaps the gloss macros from gb4e can be of help.

Comment: Please edit your question and re-upload your picture using the interface here, i.e. the button above the box with your question.

Comment: May you fix the link to the picture?

Answer (score 4):

I have to experience in this type of music. But it seems that you want some fancy align/verbantim stuff to typeset it.

Ideally a new package needs to be designed for this.

I seems that ConTeXt with Auctex and table editing mode can greatly simplify such typesetting for you.

Samples:     http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE
Auctex help: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/More_AUCTeX

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[0.10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{shadow}
\usepackage{tikz}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  %  To make the linespacing in the document 1.5cm
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}  %  To make the linespacing in the document 1.5cm
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,color,geometry,fancyhdr,subfigure, multicol,multirow}
\geometry{left=0.31in,right=1in}
\geometry{top=1.1in,bottom=1in}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  %  To make the linespacing in the document 1.5cm
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}  %  To make the linespacing in the document 1.5cm
\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{color}\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage{subfigure}\usepackage{multicol}\usepackage{multirow}%\usepackage[T1]{fontec}
\usepackage{listings}



\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\author{Ananth}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ \left\{
\begin{array}{l|llllll|llllll|llllll|lllll}
\rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:m} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:l} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:d.f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{t_{1}} & :- & \rm{:d.r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:m} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{r} & :- & \rm{:f.l} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{m} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}.s_{1}} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-
\end{array}\right\} \]

\vspace{2mm}
\[ \left\{
\begin{array}{l|llllll|llllll|llllll|lllll}
\rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:m} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:l} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:d.f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{t_{1}} & :- & \rm{:d.r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:m} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{r} & :- & \rm{:f.l} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{m} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}.s_{1}} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-
\end{array}\right\| \]
 Kerui:

\vspace{2mm}
\[ \left\{
\begin{array}{l|llllll|llllll|llllll|lllll}
\rm{:d} & \rm{f} & :- & \rm{:m} & |\rm{l} & :-\rm{.l} & \rm{:l} & \rm{s} & :- & :- & |- & :- & \rm{:m} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:s.m} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:m} & \rm{r} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :-\rm{.d} & \rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:d.t_{1}} & |\rm{l_{1}} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{t_{1}} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & |\rm{t_{1}} & :-\\
\rm{:m} & \rm{l} & :- & \rm{:l} & |\rm{f} & :-\rm{.f} & \rm{:f} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:m} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:s.s} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:s} & |\rm{s} & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{f_{1}} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & |\rm{f_{1}} & :-\rm{.f_{1}} & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d.r} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :-
\end{array}\right\} \]

\vspace{2mm}
\[ \left\{
\begin{array}{l|llllll|llllll|llllll|lllll}
\rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:m} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:l} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:d.f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:r} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & \rm{t_{1}} & :- & \rm{:d.r} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:t_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:m} & \rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:s} & \rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & |\rm{m} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{r} & :- & \rm{:f.l} & |\rm{s} & :- & \rm{:f} & \rm{m} & :- & :- & |- & :-\\
\rm{:d} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & \rm{:d} & |\rm{d} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:s_{1}.s_{1}} & |\rm{s_{1}} & :- & \rm{:f_{1}} & \rm{d} & :- & :- & |- & :-
\end{array}\right\| \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You do know that `\rm` a) does *not* have an argument but is a switch and b) is deprecated 20 years (!) ago, right?

Comment: I just noticed that the content created seems to be related to your question [Is there any package in latex for typing song in solfa notation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366178/95547)